Bounding a function below using the exponential function based on a bound on the derivative of the function.
I am trying to prove the following:
Suppose $f '(x) \geq xf(x) \,\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$.  Prove that there exists a constant $k$ such that $f(x) \geq ke^x$ for all x.
I have tried setting $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$, taking its derivative, using the above inequality, and then trying to show that $g$ is bounded below, but have not been able to get this to work.

Maybe it requires more information about $f$ (e.g. $f(0)>0$).
Multiplying $e^{-x^2/2}$, we obtain
$$
  f'(x)e^{-x^2/2}-xe^{-x^2/2}f(x)\ge 0.
$$
It implies
$$
  \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\bigg)\ge0.
$$
Hence,
$$
  f(x)e^{-x^2/2}\ge f(0)\Longrightarrow f(x)\ge f(0)e^{x^2/2}.
$$
Clearly, there exists some $c>0$ such that $e^{x^2/2}\ge ce^{x}$. Set $k=cf(0)$, since $f(0)>0$, one gets
$$
  f(x)\ge ke^{x}.
$$
